# Shopp plugin in wordpress - prevent redirect after adding product

Tags: wordpress, shopp

I am using shopp plugin with my wordpress site. Normally when I press the 'add to cart' button on a product's page, it will add the product and redirect to the cart page. I want to stop the redirect and make it just stay on the same page after the product's been added.

I plan to add a modal window using bootstrap to show a message showing the updated contents of the cart, but that's another story.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch the add-to-cart button to ajax-mode which will prevent the redirecting to the cart page, as described here https://shopplugin.net/api/product-add-to-cart/ . Take a look at the examples.